# No module named spacy

Tags: ubuntu, bash, python, path, pip

I am trying to download then 'en' spacy module for ubuntu 16.04. I tried installing it as given in the documentation

```
pip install -U spacy
```

This worked fine, next I used

```
python -m spacy download en
```

This execution gave back this

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named spacy
```

I do not have a solid understanding of how Python environments and pip work, but I guessed it had something to do with my PATH

[PATH in Bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfBvq.png)

Can I know what's going wrong? What should I change for a successful installation?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem with spacy today myself. I'm not 100% too sure why it's responding differently to every other package however here's the working solution.

Spacy seems to recognise the path of the absolute location of python rather than the relative link in the virtual environment on ubuntu.

For me I encountered the problem with the virtual environment but this will work at the global level (I'm actually assuming you encountered this in a virtual environment).

Use the command
`which python`
For me the response is:
`/home/wccdev/insight/spacy-test/venv/bin/python`

Now to install, instead of:
`python -m spacy download en`
Use the path to the python you're using which is the above:
`/home/wccdev/insight/spacy-test/venv/bin/python -m spacy download en`

For the virtual environment the PYTHONPATH might need to change to the working directory.

When you enter python from your working directory, and import scrapy it won't work. However, use the absolute path to that version of python and import scrapy and you will see it works.

It appears to be an issue with scrapy, but I've only just started using it today and can't comment any further!

If you have a test script for instance you'll need to run it with the absolute path to the virtual environment.